# How can I request the url for the top tweet of a hashtag using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, discord.js

I am attempting to make a Discord bot that will post the top tweet of a hashtag when requested however I cannot figure out how to do this. I cant find anything for searching tweets of a hashtag in the Twitter API. How can I achieve this? Alternate solutions are welcome but I need it to be a Discord bot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [search API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query)? There's an example for a hashtag right there:

> **Standalone operators** can be used alone or together with any other
> operators (including those that require conjunction).
>
> For example, the following query will work because it uses the
> `#hashtag` operator, which is standalone:
>
> `#twitterapiv2`

You will need to do some work in your code to decide what constitutes "the top tweet" - do you mean the most recent Tweet, the Tweet with most likes, the most retweets, etc - you will have to check the metrics on the Tweet objects to decide which Tweet is "top" in your definition, there's nothing built-in to the API that returns just the "top" Tweet, unless you just want the most recent result.

Comment: I am not sure how i missed that, sorry. i dont need the API to find the top one, i will be implementing that myself. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [this api reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) they have a custom query thing going on. I'm sure you should be able to use their query options to get the data you want

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. There is a possibility that the URL will change or be deprecated. If you don't want to/have time to formulate a complete answer, you can drop links in the comments section to give the OP a starting point